# "living banner"

Tags: grammar

*There is also an extract from Leon Trotsky's memoirs, in which he says Sverdlov told him: "Ilyich Lenin thought we shouldn't leave them [the imperial family] a living banner in such hard times.*"

Source: https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/last-tsar-killed-on-orders-of-lenin-say-romanov-family-358024.html

Just wanna ask whether before "a living banner" "as" shouldn’t be. It does not make much sense to me without it. Bolsheviks did not want to release the tsar family because they could be perceived as a symbol (living banner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that quote, it would make more sense with "as".

However, there are two difficulties. One is that it's a translated text. The other is that someone has edited `[the imperial family]` into the text, that is, someone has decided that "them" means the imperial family. It seems possible that original sentence might have meant "we shouldn't leave them [the tsarists] a living banner [the family] to rally around.

Comment: Excellent point.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakov_Sverdlov#Romanov_family) suggests that the relevant referent for "them" is the anti-Soviet *White Army*.  If so, "them" is an indirect object, "a living banner" is a direct object, and the two objects do not share a referent.  That's a different situation than having "them" as a direct object and "[as] a living banner" as an object complement and a second reference to the same referent.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Great find in the Wikipedia article.